# How do I turn off the error warning info count icons in Edge (Chrome) Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, edge-devtools

[image]

I'd easily could have 1 or 2 more tabs in that row if it weren't for those icons.

I don't want those, I want more space for tabs. If there's a setting for turning it off, it doesn't seem to have an obvious name. I've already went through the whole settings list and didn't find anything.

Comment: There's no such setting. You can write an extension that adds a custom devtools theme and hide these via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what wOxxOm has said, DevTools currently has not such setting to disable these `Issues` buttons. However, since the purpose is to have more space for tabs, I actually have 2 suggestions for you (or workarounds I suppose): **Use Focus Mode** or **dock DevTools to bottom**.

1. **Focus Mode**. Focus Mode pins all the tab buttons to the left, so they will not be "squeezed" by `Issues` buttons. To turn on Focus Mode, go to `Settings -->  Experiments --> Focus Mode`.
2. **Dock DevTools to bottom**. It is another workaround that simply gives you more space horizontally.